# Is there any software solution for sharing Internet connection (PPTP connection) with other computers on LAN?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, internet-connection

I have three computers at home. I used the computer connected to internet as a gateway by enabling Internet Connection Sharing (Windows XP). And all computers could access the internet fine. Now, the broadband service provider has changed the internet setup and I need to dial in a PPTP connection first and after that I can access the internet.

The problem is that the PPTP connection doesn't have an option for Internet connection sharing. I tried using proxies, HTTP/FTP, but that only works for specific services and the  applications which need to connect to custom ports for updates or other communication still don't work. Is there any software solution to allow complete internet access from other computers?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't simply buy a router?

Answer (score 0):

[Untangle for Windows](http://wiki.untangle.com/index.php/Quick_Install_Guide:_Untangle_for_Windows) is no longer actively developed but it should work fine for your requirements.